# Ajuda JSON Delphi

Tags: json, delphi

Boa tarde!

Poderia me ajudar a ler esse arquivo JSON em Delphi. Já tentei inúmeras classes, inclusive a nativa do Delphi e consegui lêr apenas os dados do primeiro nódulo, como status.
Utilizo a versão Delphi XE6.

```
{  
   "erro":{  
      "status":400,
      "tipo":"requisicao",
      "causas":[  
         {  
            "codigo":"4210BC95",
            "mensagem":"Banco Caixa Econômica Federal - Campo (boleto.conta.convenio) - O formato do convênio é de até 7 dígitos (6  dígitos + dígito verificador) e deve ser (dddddd-d), onde (d) = numérico, representa um dígito numérico de zero a n ove, mas o informado foi (65).",
        "suporte":"http://www.boletocloud.com/app/dev/api"
     },
     {  
        "codigo":"980D273F",
        "mensagem":"Banco Caixa Econômica Federal - Campo (boleto.conta.agencia) - O formato da agência de 4 dígitos deve ser (dddd), mínimo 1 dígito e máximo 4 dígitos, onde (d) = numérico, representa um dígito numérico de zero a nove, mas o informado foi (45125).",
           "suporte":"http://www.boletocloud.com/app/dev/api"
         }
     ]
   }
}
```

Comment: Como está o seu código?

Comment: Vê se te ajuda esses dois link... http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/89379/como-ler-um-ficheiro-json-usando-o-delphi http://balaiotecnologico.blogspot.com.br/2013/07/lendo-dados-json-em-aplicacoes-delphi.html

Comment: Fiz vários códigos com várias classes do JSON. Já tinha visto esse tutorial, mas não tinha entendido o conceito do nódulo de array. Obrigado!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Criei um projeto como exemplo. Eu usei o Delphi Seattle mas creio que funcione no X6 também. Veja abaixo:

Adicione no `uses`:

```
System.JSON
```

Adicione um `TMemo` e coloque nele o texto `JSON` que você passou na sua pergunta. Adicione um `TButton` e coloque o código abaixo no `OnClick`

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
    JSonObjectAsString: string;
    JSObj             : TJSONObject;
    JSArray           : TJSONArray;
    JSValue           : TJSONValue;
begin
    JSonObjectAsString := Memo1.Text;

    JSObj := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(JSonObjectAsString) as TJSONObject;
    try
        // Erro
        Memo1.Lines.Add(JSObj.GetValue('erro').ToJSON);
        // Status
        Memo1.Lines.Add((JSObj.GetValue('erro') as TJSONObject).GetValue('status').ToJSON);
        // tipo
        Memo1.Lines.Add((JSObj.GetValue('erro') as TJSONObject).GetValue('tipo').ToJSON);
        // causas
        JSArray := (JSObj.GetValue('erro') as TJSONObject).GetValue('causas') as TJSONArray;
        for JSValue in JSArray do
        begin
            // código
            Memo1.Lines.Add((JSValue as TJSONObject).GetValue('codigo').ToJSON);
            // mensagem
            Memo1.Lines.Add((JSValue as TJSONObject).GetValue('mensagem').ToJSON);
            // suporte
            Memo1.Lines.Add((JSValue as TJSONObject).GetValue('suporte').ToJSON);
        end;
    finally
        JSObj.DisposeOf;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: Obrigado Daniel. Deu certo, só tiver que alterar o .ToJson que não tem no DELPHI XE6 para ToString. Tem como já vir removido as duplas aspas automaticamente, pois estou tendo retorno com elas. Os exemplos que eu estava vendo só usava Child(xx). Por que usou o JSValue apenas para o array?

Comment: Consegui remover, fazendo isso. Não sei se a melhor maneira, mas foi assim: `Memo2.Lines.Add((JSValue as TJSONObject).GetValue('codigo').ToString.Replace('"',''));`

Comment: Os elementos de um `JSONArray` podem ser de qualquer tipo de `JSON`. No Delphi o `TJSONValue` é o pai de todos os tipos de `JSON`. Por isso usei o `TJSONValue` e depois fiz um `cast` para o tipo conhecido. No caso `TJSONObject`.